# Implementing Multi day averages in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the following structure which is simplified for the scope of this question:

```
  A        B        C          E F G 
0 location 2016/9/1 2016/9/1   n 2 1 
1 location 2016/9/2 2016/9/2   2 n 2 
2 location 2016/9/3 2016/9/3   1 1 1 
3 location 2016/9/4 2016/9/4   1 n n  
4 location 2016/9/5 2016/9/5   1 1 1 
5 location 2016/9/6 2016/9/6   1 n n 
6 location 2016/9/7 2016/9/7   1 n 1  
7 location 2016/9/8 2016/9/8   1 1 1  
8 location 2016/9/9 2016/9/9   1 1 1
```

Where s is a string value and covers dates and times and other data, n is a np.nan value and f is a float value.

What I wish to do is create a dataframe which has 2 or 3 columns of the first 4 columns and from there create a 7 day running average. I am able to set up a rolling window like so:

```
df = df.rolling(7).mean()
```

However this simply produces a dataframe with only nan values where all the f values are located in my above example.

Another approach I have tried is the following:

[pandas groupby and rolling_apply ignoring NaNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988123/pandas-groupby-and-rolling-apply-ignoring-nans)

However for my code it does not output the correct values I am looking for.

My goal is to create a 7 day running/moving average which can account for nan values and only average over the values which are not nan.

Using the dataframe above as an example input what I wish to achieve is the following output:

```
  A        B        C          E   F   G    
0 location 2016/9/1 2016/9/1   n   n   n   
1 location 2016/9/2 2016/9/2   n   n   n   
2 location 2016/9/3 2016/9/3   n   n   n   
3 location 2016/9/4 2016/9/4   n   n   n    
4 location 2016/9/5 2016/9/5   n   n   n    
5 location 2016/9/6 2016/9/6   n   n   n   
6 location 2016/9/7 2016/9/7   7/6 4/3 6/4  
7 location 2016/9/8 2016/9/8   8/7 1   6/4 
8 location 2016/9/9 2016/9/9   1   1   1
```

In rows 6/7/8 the cumulative running/moving average is calculated and the first 7 rows are blank and the averages are affected by the number of nan values present.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of your input and desired output?

Comment: Updated with clarified inputs and outputs.

Comment: add some actual dates you cant to aggregate over and replace the `f` with random numbers or so

Comment: @cd123, i think you can do `df.fillna(0).rolling(window=7).mean()`. I'm not sure though since you did give an example of how columns G through L are computed. Also, do you want to perform aggregations on columns A to D?

Comment: I've simplified it the dataframe for easier calculation/usage. I ideally want to keep the data tied to each row intact with column A through C kept the same however in column B/C if possible to set a start and end date of the moving average which I can extract easily and then the 7 day running average computed as shown above.

Comment: I have tried the df.fillna(0).rolling(7).mean() but it counts the extra zero values into the average calculation and doesn't produce the value I am looking for.

Comment: can you tell me how you got row 6, col F? should it be 4/3 instead of 5/4?

Comment: My bad, a few errors I made when changing the dataframe around.

Comment: i think row 6 and 7 for col G should both have 6/5.. i'll be posting my answer soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest approach I could think of but this can certainly be improved:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# setup DataFrame
A = ['location']*9
B = pd.date_range(start='2016/9/1', periods=9)
C = pd.date_range(start='2016/9/1', periods=9)
E = [np.NaN, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
F = [2, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, np.NaN, 1, 1]
G = [1, 2, 1, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, 1, 1, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(A, B, C, E, F, G)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G'])

# compute values for columns E, F, and G
df_ = df.loc[:, ['E', 'F', 'G']]
numerator = df_.fillna(0).rolling(window=7, min_periods=7).sum()
denominator = df_.notnull().astype(int).rolling(window=7).sum()

# New DataFrame containing results for columns E, F, and G
new_df = numerator / denominator

# final DataFrame
final_df = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].join(new_df)
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: This looks to be something I can use, just need to adapt it a little then it should be good. Thank you very much :)